# Avoiding orphans at the start of quote/quotation environments

Tags: page-breaking, quoting, widows-orphans

To me, orphans -- page breaks after the first line of a paragraph -- are tolerable in the normal text body, and so I leave TeX's default settings (`\clubpenalty=150`) alone. On the other hand, I want to get rid of orphans at the start of `quote`/`quotation` environments.

- My first (naïve?) attempt was to define a new environment based on `quote` and set `\clubpenalty=10000` within this environment; this still produced orphans.
- After rummaging through the [LaTeX2e sources](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf), I tried to embed `\@afterheading` (p. 287) into my custom environment; this resulted in an error message.
- Finally (and out of sheer desparation), I inserted `\@nobreaktrue` (which is used in `\@afterheading`) into my custom environment; this *worked*.

This poses the following questions:

- Why did my attempt at locally redefining `\clubpenalty` fail?
- What does `\@nobreaktrue` do? Are there adverse effects?
- If the latter is the case, what is the proper way to avoid orphans at the start of `quote`/`quotation` environments?

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\textwidth}{350pt}

\newenvironment{failednoorphanquote}{\begin{quote}\clubpenalty=10000\relax}{\end{quote}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{noorphanquote}{\begin{quote}\@nobreaktrue}{\end{quote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\end{quote}

\chapter{blubb}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{failednoorphanquote}
\blindtext
\end{failednoorphanquote}

\chapter{foo}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{noorphanquote}
\blindtext
\end{noorphanquote}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: In response to Martin Scharrer's answer: I'm looking for a solution that (unlike `\Needspace`) does not make implicit assumptions about the vertical space above the `quote` environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\@nobreaktrue` is the correct way to do this. The reason it works is that the `quote` environment eventually does something like

```
\everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
        \@nobreakfalse
        \clubpenalty=10000
    \else
        \clubpenalty=150
    \fi
}
```

so your `\clubpenalty` is being overridden.

To answer your other questions, `\@nobreaktrue` expands to `\global\let\if@nobreak\iftrue`. There are no adverse effects because if it is true, then it is immediately (globally) set back to false as soon as the paragraph has started.

Comment: Thanks! With hindsight, I should have searched in `source2e` not only for `\@nobreaktrue`, but also for `\if@nobreak`.

Comment: @lockstep: I just used the `trace` package to trace the invocation of `failednoorphanquote` to see what was going wrong with `\clubpenalty`.

Comment: Can this be done in the `verse` environment (provided by the package of the same name)?

Answer (score 5):

A few months after I had asked this question, I released my [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package. Its new environment of the same name offers, among other things, control of orphans at the start of it – disable them for individual environments with `\begin{quoting}[noorphanfirst]` and globally with `\usepackage[noorphanfirst]{quoting}`. (There's also a related option `noorphanafter`.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\textwidth}{350pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{quoting}
\blindtext
\end{quoting}

\chapter{blubb}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{quoting}[noorphanfirst]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer why `\clubpenalty` fails and `\@nobreaktrue` works, but here an alternative solution:

You can use the `needspace` package to force a pagebreak before the quote if the space isn't enough for two lines:

```
\usepackage{needspace}
\newenvironment{noorphanquote}{\Needspace*{3\baselineskip}\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}
```

Here `3\baselineskip` is used for the skip above the quote plus two lines. You might want to refine this value.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a solution that does not make implicit assumptions about the vertical space above the `quote` environment.

Comment: @lockstep: Like I wrote: You might want to refine that value. I couldn't find the correct dimension and I'm aware that it is a stretchable amount. You might also put the `\Needspace` inside the quote environment to avoid this issue.

Comment: By default, the vertical space is mutable -- it's either `\topsep` or `\topsep` plus `\partopsep`, depending on whether the `quote` environment starts a new paragraph or not.